# How can I checkout the search center results page?

Tags: 2010, search, search-results

My search center results page has no ribbon.
In order to edit a webpart, I had to add
search/Pages/results.aspx?ToolPaneView=2

Now when I modify a webpart it wont let me, because it say the page is not in checkout.

But there is no checkout button. so! any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the pages library. You can check out the page(as list item) for the default view.
Then you can add the webpart as you are doing

Comment: How can I go to the pages library? for some reason this search center, has no ribbon, nor menu, so I dont know the direct url

Comment: I figured it out how.

Comment: Navigate to /search/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx